# Как запретить переход по ссылкам WordPress сайта и индексирование их поисковиками?

Tags: wordpress

Есть Landing page на WordPress, информация для страницы хранится в виде новостей и категорий.
Как отключить все страницы новостей и оставить только главную страницу, и запретить индексирование этих страниц поисковиками?

Comment: Зачем одностраничник сажать на вордресс ?

Comment: тут более понятно пояснили..... https://wiki.rookee.ru/noindex/

Answer (score 0):

> Как отключить все страницы новостей и оставить только главную
>   страницу, и запретить индексирование этих страниц поисковиками?

Самое надёжное - сделать редиректы со всех созданных страниц на морду.